# Taskpane app/add-in doesn't load on Office 2016

Tags: excel, ms-word, office-js, office-app

I have an Office Taskpane app/add-in that runs on both Word and Excel. Originally the app/add-in has been done by using VS2013.

The app/add-in manifest has been put to the on-prem SharePoint 2013 app catalog. Also the Trusted App Catalogs url has been set on the clients Office settings.

The app/add-in runs fine on Office 2013, but not on Office 2016. Users who have updated to the Office 2016, the app/add-in is not available under MY ORGANIZATION (see the picture). If the users (using Office 2016) are opening the document that has the app/add-in already in place, it doesn't load (see the picture).

[App/add-in problems on Office 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbRTJ.png)

The AppsManifest is below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--Published:70EDFC97-B41D-43C5-B751-7C00AD999804-->
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>49a3dd08-058c-4bbc-ba7b-444fa172bd06</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>developer</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>fi-FI</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Proo Projektin metatiedot" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Hakee projektin metatiedot ja päivittää ne dokumenttiin." />
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
    <Capability Name="Document" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://removed.removed.fi/App/Home/Home.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: I updated the app/add-in Microsoft.Office.js nuget from 1.1.0.5 to 1.1.0.11. It didn't help.

Comment: FYI - the information that you've deleted in the image can be seen from the manifest

Comment: If you go to File>Options>Trust Center>Trusted Catalogs do you see your SP catalog listed there?  If not, could you add it and try again, maybe paste a picture of the configuration if possible?

Comment: The Trusted App Catalogs setting are similar on Office 2013 and Office 2016. Both Offices are pointing to the same SharePoint App Catalog. I have on one computer installed Office 2013 and Office 2016 side by side. On the Office 2013 app work but not on Office 2016.

Comment: SOLVED: Microsoft updated Office 2016. The fix will be delivered via Windows Update.